# Blender Cycles Render - CPU is running 100% with Optix?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, gpu

After a long time, I built a new computer with an i9 12900k and an RTX 3090. Now, in Blender, I only clicked on the graphics card in the System Preferences under Cycles Render Devices and set it to GPU Compute in the project. But if I want to render something now, the CPU suddenly goes to 100% and the GPU workload is at a maximum of 10%. With CUDA everything works normally. Does anyone know what could be causing this or if I need to set something else? Strangely enough, the loading times to open a project are still very long. All other programs run without any problems and the SSD is a Samsung 980 Pro, which is not really slow normally.. Many Thanks!

[image]

Kind Regards,
Tim

Comment: Sounds like it's not actually using your GPU. Are your graphics drivers up to date? Could you maybe show us a screenshot of your settings?

Comment: I´ve now found out that the problem is only appearing if i set the Cycles Render Device to  Optix. If i set it to CUDA, everything works normally.. But why??

Comment: Yes, i just set up the PC yesterday and installed the latest drivers.

Comment: Is it over the complete rendering process that the CPU is 100% and the GPU 10%? Or just at the beginning, while the CPU is preparing the data for rendering?

Comment: Yes it´s over the complete rendering process. If i select CUDA everything is normal and the CPU only runs at 10 - 20%.

Comment: Try reinstalling Blender. Try another 3d software and see if it can utilize your GPU properly and compare your benchmark results to other people's benchmark results with the same setup.

Comment: Judging by the speed, the GPU is already being used a lot, it's somehow more of a problem that the CPU is being used too much only on Optix. And even if it works with other 3D programs, that wouldn't help me much. In general, the other programs seem to run great.

Comment: Upgrade your Blender to 3.1

Comment: I'm experiencing the issue. I'm not sure if it's normal or not. Could you find out if that's normal with Optix? Because I don't have that issue with Cuda and I have with Optix just like you.

Comment: Hi, im with i9 11th and 3080 and with Cycles and Optix my cpu is below 50% of usage but my temps are spiking 100c. Even with my CPU unchecked on OPTIX and using only GPU, my GPU is at 47c with 5% usage during render. WTH. Im gonna install another version of blender to be sure.